# Running a macro in an Excel add-in via interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I have an Excel workbook that installs an add-in with macros. After I load this workbook via Excel interop, I want to run those add-in macros from code. I'm not sure how to reference them, tho.

I've been executing macros that live in the loaded workbook's modules without issues, like this:

```
private Application m_Application; 
...
string version = m_Application.Run("Data.GetVersion");
```

But now `GetVersion` doesn't live in the workbook's `Data` module anymore. It's contained in a `Data` module *in the add-in*. What is the correct syntax for calling it?

Comment: Assuming an .xlam add-in: `m_Application.Run("'add-in name.xlam'!Data.GetVersion")`

Comment: Thanks. Once I get that to run (turns out that Excel is looking for the file in my default Documents directory unless I qualify the complete path to the file), I get the dreaded `"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472"`. Of course that might have any number of reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't need the path if the add-in is open in Excel. I couldn't really comment on a generic error like that, certainly not without seeing the macro code.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting the runtime exception `"Sorry, we couldn't find C:\\Users\\user.name\\Documents\\Logic.xlam. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"` The workbook I have opened via Interop has the .xlam referenced, and its modules show up in the VBA editor. (My macros run correctly when I invoke everything inside an Excel session, as well.) Is there a way to get a list of all add-ins in Interop so that I can check what is loaded, and what the file references are?

Comment: What was the error when you didn't include the path?

Comment: See above. It excepts with the message that it can't find the .xlam file. When I provide a fully qualified path, I get 0x800AC472. I might add that my add-in file is not in Excel's default directory - I'm browsing for it.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code showing how the application, workbook and add-in were loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'll update this Q later. Right now I'm going to embedd the modules back in the actual .xlsm as a workaround, gotta make a deadline real quick :)